# How to fix strange rendered texture?

Tags: modeling

i recently purchased the realistic nature asset pack and realistic tree pack from CG Geek, however when I append them and look at them in a rendered view they show with weird pinks, blues and purples instead of the normal textures. Can someone help me fix this or should I refund them.

Comment: are you sure this is not the normal maps that you've plugged into a diffuse node?

Comment: Also check File menu -> External Data -> Missing Files you might not have the texture images in a the right place.